# Why are there some System Properties missing, when using join in query? (powershell, get-wmiobject)

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm, wql

I ran into following problem:

When i´m running a query where there is a join inside, then the systemproperty "__PATH" is empty. When im running it without the Join, everything works fine:

## Working:

```
$apps = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($siteCode) -ComputerName $($siteserver) -Query `
"SELECT * FROM SMS_Application where IsLatest='true' and IsExpired='false' and LocalizedDisplayName like '%hydro%'"

$apps[0].__PATH
```

Output: "\SCCM\root\SMS\site_CMT:SMS_Application.CI_ID=16781953"

## Not working:

```
$apps = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($siteCode) -ComputerName $($siteserver) -Query `
"SELECT * FROM SMS_Application as App join SMS_ObjectContainerItem as FI on App.ModelName=FI.InstanceKey where App.IsLatest='true' and IsExpired='false' and LocalizedDisplayName like '%hydro%'"

$apps[1].app.__PATH
```

My Question:
Can anyone explain to me why the Path is empty?
Thanks a lot, Regards

Comment: In the non working example do you get any output from `$apps`

Comment: Actually I think your issue is that WQL does not support joins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583601/joining-two-tables-in-wql-sccm

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised the `Get-WmiObject` doesn't throw "Invalid Query" or similar

Comment: @Matt Yes the output is an object whitch contains all 2 tables. It is possible to view them with their Alias: $apps.App respectively $apps.FI

Both of them work fine (no error or anything) except that the second one has no path.